# Asus Zenbook UX31E heats up and fan works constantly with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, asus, overheating

I bought the Asus Zenbook UX31E a few days ago and installed Ubuntu 12.04. Everything works well, but the CPU temperature (and overall the machine) seems too hot and the fan works too often, even with moderate or no CPU load.

I understand that there where similar issues in the past, but I thought these where resolved (I had the same issues with a Dell and 10.04, but it almost went away eventually after some updates).

I've installed **Psensor** and it reports around 81C, after a fresh boot and minimal load (12% CPU) and the fan is constantly on.

Anyone with suggestions?

*Note*: This laptop only has an Integrated Graphics Chip.

Comment: I enabled aspm as per the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#Power_Saving_Optimizations and saw some improvement

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your software install. This is a known problem with the "Sandy Bridge" architecture of the CPU. Historically, this CPU runs hot resulting in the fan running constantly. There are few options for cooling the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Sandy bridge aspm fix is already in the kernel so that shouldn't be an issue at all. Also it seems like 12% load on idle is a bit on higher side. I have a ASUS K53E laptop with Sandybridge icore5 and it runs cool summer or winter even under load. Temps never ever cross 50C. Try updating your BIOS.